# where do I find a tool for configuration management?

Tags: configuration-management

I am looking real hard for a simple tool that could really help a lot.
I am looking for an online tool, but a installable software is also an option.
This tool should

- edit a [yaml](http://www.yaml.org/start.html) by "dumb" users who don't have access to code and git
- Have access to that yaml online via a url.
- Show that Yaml to users

The purpose is simply a configuration management system on the fly. 
I have looked so hard for this, and I can't believe there aren't simple 5 minute setup tools that do this.

please help.

Comment: What OS will it be running on? Should it be self-hosted?

Comment: self hosted. not looking to install anything!! online edit tool. what do you have in mind?

Comment: **see also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998832/gui-based-or-web-based-json-editor-that-works-like-property-explorer